# Multiplying a number with a fraction

Tags: java, math, floating-point, division, bigdecimal

I was writing some converters of units using BigDecimals and I ran across a situation where I had to multiply a number with a fraction - periodic number.

For most cases the precision is good enough, but lets say we have an equation like:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(90)
          .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(10)
                              .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(90), 6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```

Normally this would equal 10, however because of rounding, we will get 9.999999...

Is there an elegant way of implementing this without having an if condition detecting when the fraction can be cut?

Comment: If you want to deal correctly with fractions, you'll need a `Fraction` class of some kind.  Either roll your own, or have a look at what Apache provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(90)
    .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(10))
    .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(90), 6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

The difference is that here the operations are chained, which allows for resolving such cases. In your solution the division needs to be calculated (where error occurs) and then multiplication, because it's passed as argument.

Comment: Awesome. Normally I prefer having parenthesis everywhere when it comes to math in code. Just makes reading and reasoning about the order of operations a lot easier. Didn't realize it interferes with precision. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if this will be a general case answer for you, but it works in the example given:

```
bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(90)
               .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(10))
               .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(90));
```

Multiply by 10 *then* divide by 90.

```
a * x = ax
    -   --
    z    z
```

You will need to include some rounding logic for rational numbers:

```
bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(1)
               .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1))
               .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
```

Will fail without rounding.